# MFC - How to set the toolbar title?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

The title of the toolbar and also the menu item ID_VIEW_TOOLBAR remains empty. I have tried to set it within `CMainFrame::OnCreate`:

```
CString strToolbar;
strToolbar.LoadStringA(IDS_TOOLBAR_STANDARD); // IDS_TOOLBAR_STANDARD = "Standard"
m_wndToolBar.SetWindowText(strToolbar);
DockPane(&m_wndToolBar);
m_wndToolBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
EnablePaneMenu(TRUE, ID_ANSICHT_ANPASSEN, "Anpassen", ID_VIEW_TOOLBAR);
```

The menu Looks like following:

[image: Empty ID_VIEW_TOOLBAR title]

Do you know how to set it properly?

Comment: This looks more like a menu item than like a window title. As far as I understand `[<empty>|Eigenschaften|Anpassen]` is a submenu of `[Symbolleisten und Andockfenster]`. So you are trying to set the text of a menu item with `SetWindowText`. This does not work.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: ID_VIEW_TOOLBAR is a Standard Command ID, the text from the menu editor gets overriden with an empty text. I think that the window title is used for the menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, I had create the Toolbar by explicitly specifying the ID of the Toolbar (instead of using the default argument of the function).

```
    m_wndToolBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_TOP |
        CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC,
        CRect(1,1,1,1),
        IDR_MAINFRAME) // <-- Custom ID
```

After this I could set the title of the toolbar to what I want:

```
m_wndToolBar.SetWindowText(_T("My Toolbar Name");
```

I got it working after reading [this thread](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?544975-RESOLVED-CMFCToolBar-issue-Can-t-change-title).

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking people do not change the display text of standard commands at runtime. At compile time you can set the ID's menu text in [in the string table section of the resource editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdfxk9a4.aspx).

If you want to change the menu text at runtime, you can add an ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI handler for ID_VIEW_TOOLBAR and call CCmdUI::SetText inside the handler. When the user click a top level menu to display a drop-down menu, a WM_INITMENUPOPUP is sent to the owner of the menu, in this case your CFrameWnd-derived class. CFrameWnd::OnInitMenuPopup then iterates through each menu item and calls the update command UI handlers if exists.

Reference
[MFC TN021: Command and Message Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt2c310k.aspx)